# how to store data into the database and generate the sum using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I create this form, and when I press the save button, the number of calculations from each row will appear in the column nilai. And I want to store each column in the database.

and heres the code:

```
<?php foreach ($siswa as $row){
                    
                    echo "<tr>  <td width='100'>$row->nis</td>
                                <td>".  strtoupper($row->nama)."</td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_1".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas1($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_2".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas2($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_3".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas3($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_4".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas4($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='nilai_akhir".$row->nis."' value='' class='form-control'></td></tr>";
                }
            ?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that a database table is not a spreadsheet. Seriously consider normalising your schema.

Answer (score 0):

If save button is form submit event, consider to do the operation on the server-side. Otherwise, just call every function at the  iteration and sum them up.

```
<?php foreach ($siswa as $row){
                    
                    echo "<tr>  <td width='100'>$row->nis</td>
                                <td>".  strtoupper($row->nama)."</td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_1".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas1($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_2".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas2($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_3".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas3($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='tugas_4".$row->nis."' value='".  chek_tugas4($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))."' class='form-control'></td>
                                <td width='150'><input type='int' id='nilai_akhir".$row->nis."' value='".(chek_tugas1($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))+chek_tugas2($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))+chek_tugas3($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3))+chek_tugas4($row->nis, $this->uri->segment(3)))."' class='form-control'></td></tr>";
                }
            ?>
```